# Play video in splash screen with Xamain.Forms.Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to play video on splash screen with Xamarin.Forms.Android. When I start the application all I can see is a white blank screen. After the video is completed, my main activity loads as expected. I don't see any exceptions about VideoView in debug log. Can you please help or redirect me? Thank you.

I am using Xamarin.Forms shared project. I installed latest versions of Xamarin.Android.Support libraries. I created a splash layout and splash activity. Minimum Android version is 4.4 and target version is 8.1 (API level 27). I put the video in Resources\raw folder as video.mp4 file.

SplashLayout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/appSplash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/splashVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#1A1E83</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1A1E83</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#2B9E94</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>-->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <!--Back Button OverWrite-->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>

  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppToolbarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>

  <!--<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_land</item>-->
  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

VideoSplashActivity.cs

```cs
[Activity(Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class VideoSplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    VideoView videoView;

    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(VideoSplashActivity).Name;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "VideoSplashActivity.OnCreate");

        //set layout view
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashLayout);

        //access video view
        videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.splashVideo);

        //access the video
        string videoPath = $"android.resource://{Application.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.video}";
        videoView.SetVideoPath(videoPath);
        videoView.Start();

        videoView.Completion += (sender,args)=>
        {
            SimulateStartup();
        };
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        SimulateStartup();
    }

    private void SimulateStartup()
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.");
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
    }
}
```

part of the debug log

```
D/X:VideoSplashActivity(20832): VideoSplashActivity.OnCreate
D/Mono    (20832): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
D/Mono    (20832): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
D/Mono    (20832): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
D/Mono    (20832): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
D/Mono    (20832): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
D/Mono    (20832): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
D/Mono    (20832): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
D/Mono    (20832): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
D/Mono    (20832): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0xa55c6d00] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat[0xa55c6ac0]: 3
D/Mono    (20832): Image addref System[0x9417c8c0] -> System.dll[0x91551600]: 2
D/Mono    (20832): Prepared to set up assembly 'System' (System.dll)
D/Mono    (20832): Assembly System[0x9417c8c0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
D/Mono    (20832): AOT: image 'System.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/[PackageNameHere]-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.dll.so" not found
D/Mono    (20832): AOT: image '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/[PackageNameHere]-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.dll.so" not found
D/Mono    (20832): Config attempting to parse: 'System.dll.config'.
D/Mono    (20832): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/sdks/out/android-armeabi-v7a-release/etc/mono/assemblies/System/System.config'.
D/Mono    (20832): Assembly Ref addref netstandard[0x9417c620] -> System[0x9417c8c0]: 2
D/Mono    (20832): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0xa55c6d00] -> Mono.Android[0x9417b960]: 32
D/Mono    (20832): Assembly Ref addref [AppNameHere].Droid[0xa55c49c0] -> Rg.Plugins.Popup[0xa55c5c80]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
D/X:VideoSplashActivity(20832): Startup work is finished - starting MainActivity.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    SimulateStartup();
}
```

It seems the problem is "SimulateStartup()" method in OnResume override. I removed it then video played as expected.